Azure Logic App - Outlook Password change
I have to create a workflow using standard Azure Logic App.
Workflow has been created on the trigger - "When a new email arrives". Outlook connector has been configured and workflow is executed as expected.
But as per password policy, password has to be change in every 30 days. Is there any way to automatically update (using key vault secret and Azure logic app parameter) the password or do we need to manually update the password.
Thanks in advance.

I ran into similar issue recently and it looks like we need to manually authorize the o365 connectors again in case of any changes to the creds.
It is recommended to use an service account which is free from password changes mostly so you won't end up here.
When you want to update password for service account, plan it along with your deployment so you redeploy your connector with updated creds.

There is no way that I know of to automatically update this password because it is not the password that is at issue, it is the Oauth tokens that are generated by a successful authentication, using the password. Where I work accounts that are used by automation are exempt from password rotation, we are satisfied with MFA and conditional access based on device compliance, basically the account is only usable on a company device and if you can meet the MFA requirements.

We create a secret for outlook365 password and a parameter in Azure logic app. Can we use this parameter to authenticate outlook account in case of password change?

No. The password is not the problem here. The password is used to generate Oauth tokens, which the connector caches. When the password expires, those tokens are also expired, forcing the re-authentication. So to you, it may look like the password is the problem but it is not really the case.
